# .NET 5 Web API Jwt Token from external issuer

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, .net-5, bearer-token

Im trying to make an .NET 5 Web Api works with Jwt Bearer token. I want some operations to be secured by using a token that comes from another issuer. The token would be generated by MS Azure AD. The application will read the token from the request header, validate it and extract the user's roles for more validations. The app shoudn't be the issuer of the token.

Is this possible? I tried so many ways to make this works without success. I setup Swagger to use OpenId Connect with Microsoft Azure and then the bearer is used to call the secured operations but always got errors. Now I don't understand how Dotnet Core Authencation and Authorization works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That will definitely work OK but requires an understanding of the science:

**AZURE AD TOKENS**

I would first look at the JWT in an online viewer. There is a known issue with the default setup where you get JWT access tokens that cannot be validated. See [Step 3 of my blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/) for details.

**UNDERSTAND PRINCIPLES**

Validating a JWT involves the general steps in [this blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/06/jwt-access-token-validation/). Once you understand this it will hopefully unblock you.

**C# JWT ACCESS TOKEN VALIDATION IN APIs**

The Microsoft framework often hides the required logic, which doesn't always help, and the option I prefer is to validate JWTs via a library.

Aim to understand how to use the JwtSecurityTokenHandler class to validate a JWT manually, eg in a console app. Maybe borrow some ideas from [this C# code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthenticator.cs).

**C# AUTHORIZATION**

Once JWT validation works, the next step is to use the details in the ClaimsPrincipal to determine whether to allow access to data. I would get on top of the JWT validation first though.